# Cannot connect to IBM PostgreSQL from pgadmin, CLI

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, npgsql

I am trying to connect to my managed PostgreSQL instance in IBM. It sometimes connects via Pgadmin. I have no success connecting via terminal or c# code (npgsql). Following is the error i get.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "someaddress.databases.appdomain.cloud" (xxx.xx.xxx.218) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 30331?
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "someaddress.databases.appdomain.cloud" (xxx.xx.xxx.98) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 30331?
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "someaddress.databases.appdomain.cloud" (xxx.xx.xxx.197) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 30331?
```

Its surprising me as to why it succeeds sometimes when tried via pgadmin. Also the error message has 3 IPs listed why is that? 
I don't think ip whitelisting is the problem otherwise error message would have been different

Answer (score 0):

The hostname must have several IP addresses assigned, which is no problem as such.

But the hosts either don't exist (at least, there is no network route to them) or are blocked by a firewall.

Comment: i actually explisted added my IP to the whitelist and this time i was successful in connecting via pgadmin, psql. But in my c# code (ODBC,Npgsql) `i get error no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.xx.xxx.241", user "****", database "ibmclouddb", SSL off` File: auth.c
    Line: 512
    Routine: ClientAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error message was misleading I did the following

1. Added my IP to whitelist in IBM console (pg_hba.conf)
2. Set SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true; in Connection string as IBM only allows connections that are encrypted